# Save a new entity delivered from another form : "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, when I tried to save a new entity delivered from another form, I got this error message:

***An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker***

Form1 :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student X = new Student();
        .
        .
        // Do some stuffs for student X
        .
        .
        // Send the student X to Form2
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2(X);
        Form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Form2 :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Student X)
    {
        this.X = X;
        DbContext School = new DbContext();
    }

    Student X;

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        .
        .
        // Do some stuffs for student X
        .
        .
        School.Student.Add(School);
        School.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you create a Context in Form1 that you attach Student X to before sending it to Form2?

Comment: As matter fact yes, one of student's navigations has a reference from another dbcontext.